# Web front-end framework & ensured cross-browser compabtibility

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I am not a skilled web-developer and my domain is mostly `Java`. That's why I have been using `GWT` as front-end for my web applications (small/middle sized).

As I have improved by `HTML` & `CSS` skills, I have been thinking of trying something more direct, lighweight  and flexible than `GWT` like angular.js or other popular front-end framework. From my experience with `GWT`, when I used my own style I experienced cross-browser differences (something I am not accustomed to as a java developer).

Is there a way or some framework which would be of assist here so I don't have to spend hours figuring out what is wrong and googling browser hack? I mean both `JavaScript` compatibility & `CSS`  compatibility (and `HTML` features compatibility if there are any issues). What framework might be good idea?

Comment: i´m a big fan of KNOCKOUT.JS  <- use it, its great

Comment: I don't think you can really escape cross-browser differences unless you develop for a single browser.

Answer (score 1):

In server side software, you control the environment. But the nature of client side software is that you are a slave to the client, whatever that may be. And to some extent you will always have to be aware of that and troubleshoot individual browsers to get things perfect everywhere.

That said, you can get the basics to be pretty rock solid with something like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), or other CSS frameworks. This gives a well tested foundation that should work reliably everywhere. However, as you build on that foundation *will* run into cross browser issues and there isn't a good way around that.

Knowing the differences that matter between supported clients one of many attributes that makes a good front end web developer.